# Run Objective-C in Xcode without starting up simulator

Tags: xcode

I would like to run my Objective-C code inside Xcode, but not for the iPhone or Mac. I want to write programs to solve the challenges from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5), without starting up the simulator. I am using `NSLog()` to display my results, and that's all I need.

How can I do this? I checked everywhere but all I found were questions about how to run Objective-C outside of Xcode and so on.

Comment: "not for the iPhone or mac" - well, it makes sense not to build for the iPhone, but if you're not building for Mac OS X, then what's your target platform?

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks,all I mean is that i dont want to create an application that has a GUI, i just want to create algorithms and print some result

Comment: Ok, right, you'll want to create a command-line app. It still targets the Mac platform though. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you want to create a "Command-Line Tool", one of the options under the Mac OS X templates:
[image]

That'll give you a project containing just one code file, main.m:

```
//  main.m
//  Project Euler Puzzle #N
//
//  Created by pnizzle on 8/7/12.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's linked against Foundation and compiled as ObjC, so you can do pretty much anything you would do in a GUI app (except the GUI parts, of course), including creating your own classes. `main()` is the entry point for your program; just put whatever you want to do inside that `@autoreleasepool` block.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the **Command Line Tool** option in Xcode is the **CodeRunner** app, available in the Mac App Store. CodeRunner allows you to run short snippets of Objective-C code without the overhead of Xcode.

CodeRunner also supports a number of other languages: C, Java, JavaScript, Lua, Perl, PHP etc

CodeRunner currently costs about $10, I have found it to be very useful to quickly test short snippets of code in a number of languages.

I believe you will need to install the **Command Line Tools** package from `Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads` for CodeRunner to use.

http://krillapps.com/coderunner/

Comment: good to know there are other options out there. Will check this codeRunner sometime soon. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Choosing "Command-Line Tool"will do the job for you. You will see the output in the bottom when you run the code.